# documentation generator for vc++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, documentation

I am looking for a plugin(s) for VS2010 that will allow me to:

1. Document my code easily.
2. Browse that documentation.
3. Export it into some format or other.

I was looking for a sort of front-end for doxygen + a documentation browser, but found nothing. Any other such tool will be great, it doesn't have to be doxygen, although it should preferably be free.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the official [Doxygen GUI](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html#latestsrc)? The documentation is usually generated within seconds and it can generate very nice HTML files.

Answer (score 1):

My addin, [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/), will help you a lot with generating and updating documentation comments. It will save a huge amount of time creating the comments as it not only provides boilerplate commetns, but also fills in as much documenation as it can to help minimise the typing you need to do to complete the docs. It makes it extremely easy to keep the docs in sync with the code. It supports comments in Documentation Xml and Doxygen (Qt or JavaDoc) formats, and the style and layout of comments is highly configurable. It handles C++, C, C++/CLI, C#, Java, and Visual Basic.

You can then process the documentation comments using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) (which also handles DocXml, Qt, JavaDoc formats) to produce external (e.g. html) documentation.

JavaDoc/Qt format comments can be made more readable than XmlDoc, but it's worth considering that Visual Studio supports XmlDoc (so you get syntax colouring in the comments, code analysis tools like FxCop and StyleCop can check the content for you, and in some languages the intellisense system can show your documentaton in tooltips as you write client code, etc. So XmlDoc is steadily gaining a lead over the other documentation formats due to the VS IDE support for it).